Cylinder spacer with rhombus cross-linked bracing
I would like to make a spacer for 3D printing that is not solid but braced with a rhombus shape to reduce material requirements. My problem is that I don't know how to cut the parts marked in yellow.

Or, if it's simpler, how can I make it with Blender? It is 30mm high, 60mm in diameter, and has a 10mm hole in the middle.

You can do it from scratch following these steps :
1. Set the Scene's Units to mm.
2. Create a (big) cylinder with depth=30, radius=30 and no cup filled.
3. Duplicate this cylinder and scale it's X and Y to 10 – then apply Scale – this is the small cylinder.
4. To the first cylinder add Solidify modifier with a positive offset (do not apply).
5. Copy this modifier to the small cylinder, but make the offset negative (do not apply).
6. Create a long plane, and add two modifiers to it: Solidify and Array – this is the half of the grid.
7. Duplicte it and flip –  this is the other half of the grid.
8. Adjust all object's positions, and also thickness for all Solidify modifiers - then apply all modifiers to planes (but not to cylinders)
9. Union planes with Bool Tools
10. Duplicate the big cylinder, delete Solidify modifier and Bool Tool>Intersect it with the grid. *That will delete redundant grid outside of the big cylinder
11. Duplicate the small cylinder, delete Solidify modifier and Bool Tool>Difference with the grid. *That will delete redundant grid inside of the small cylinder
12. Apply all modifiers for all objects.
13. Union all objects into one using Bool Tool.
14. Apply all transforms.
15. The shape is ready - now it's time to clean-up N-gons:
Edit Mode > Select All(press A) > Triangulate(press Ctrl+T)
16. Export the object as .stl
(!) NOTE: In the process of exporting set scale to 1000. It's necessary due Blender and printing software use different units: Blender uses meters, printing software use millimeters. The difference is 1000.
So while exporting .stl from Blender –  ALWAYS set scale to 1000 :


I was curios about making this form, so I also did it myself. Here:


UPD:
The model I attached previously was flawed. Now it's fixed. Changes I made:

Fixed nasty overhanged faces near to the bottom. Thanks to @MarkusvonBroady for noticing this out.

Poly-count in this case is debatable, so I've attached an Decimate modifier. If the poly-count is too high for you – then just set Ratio to value less than 1 (then apply Decimate modifier):




(!) NOTE:  Zero Faces and Zero Edges warnings are false because "zero" faces and edges in this case are NOT actually sizeless. They are just small (0.046+ mm). This is not an error and totally fine for the high poly-count. *In case this poly-count is to high to suit your purposes – just use the Decimate modifier I mentioned before.

Fixed file:

*Feel free to use my file :-)

Thank you for your answer. When you create a cylinder how many vertices are you using? Can you please specify this in your answer? It seems your mesh is way too dense than it needs to be thus creating a lot of Zero Face errors.

@Harry McKenzie, Zero-Faces are not errors. Just a possibility to dissolve details. Dissolving leads to faster printing, but facets will appear. Let the author decide what does he prefer:  faster printing or better quality. By the way, if the printer's resolution is not high enough to reproduce these details – it will print it anyway – but the same way it would print a model with lower poly-count. I suggest to use higher density because it's either "win" or "no harm". Low density - you suggested - does not lead to "win" in any case – ESPECIALLY with rounded shapes.

I'd also think a 0 area face is an error because it's non-manifold. Of course in a context where 'manifoldness' is not a requirement, or where specifically 0 area faces are allowed, this won't be a problem and therefore it won't be an error. But in general I think it's fair to call 0 area faces "errors" and OP didn't mention a particular printer so we don't know what the requirements are. Dense topology is a different issue - it can have both positive and negative effects (curvature versus speed, where the printing speed also affects quality) but 0 area faces don't actually add any detail.

Oh and there's overhang at the bottom, that might be a problem? The overhang shouldn't be there.

@MarkusvonBroady —(1) Quite often "zero" faces and edges are NOT actually sizeless. They are just small. In this case edges (also faces' sides) are 0.046+ mm. Since they form a rounded surface, where facets would be highly noticeable - such size could be suitable or redundant (but harmless) depending on the used materials and the printer itself. Though if this poly-count is too much in the author's case - I advise to use Decimate modifier. —(2) I accept overhang at the bottom as a flaw – my bad (I will fix it)

@Yaroslav oh, I thought "zero" faces are literally zero-area, not just close to zero (and what would "close" mean? It depends on scale). So yea, in such case I have to agree with you, not an error. This explains why no edges are reported as non-manifold...

@MarkusvonBroady — I've fixed overhang near the bottom of the model and updated my answer with the fixed .blend file — Huge thanks for noticing this problem out. — P.S. And since the high poly-count emerged such an extensive polemic I've also added an Decimate modifier to make poly-count easily adjustable :)

Thank you Yaroslav!
It's good that you are such a cohesive and helpful community! Have a wonderful day! I wish all the best!

It is better to start with a flat 2D mesh which we will extrude later. Install the built-in 3D Print Toolbox addon and click Check All to make sure your grid mesh Intersect Face is zero. Do the same for the circular mesh object.

Then select both the circular mesh object and the grid object and press Ctrl+J to join them. Go tab into Edit Mode and hover over the grid mesh and press L to select it then press Ctrl+F > Intersect (Knife). You can now select the inner and outer parts of the mesh you and remove it with X > Delete Faces. Then select the areas of ugly topology and do X > Limited Dissolve.

The process is not perfect so you have to do a little manual cleanup as well. Just keep checking the result of Check All button in 3D Print Toolbox panel. To make sure you don't have any 3D printing issues. For example, if it shows there are more than zero Intersecting Faces, there will appear a button under that result which you can click to highlight those faces. Fix them manually. And then you can also keep dissolving weird or redundant vertices/edges with X > Dissolve Vertices/Edges. Until you can come up with some cleaner topology:

Once you are happy with the topology, then extrude the mesh:

If you need more resolution you can add a circle with more vertices like in this example 128 vertices with this topology using Ctrl+E > Bridge Edge Loops

Then after Ctrl+F > Intersect (Knife) and some cleanup:

Triangulate and then extrude. Here is the model with cleaner topology with the exact dimensions you were looking for:



@Yaroslav I downloaded your blend file and checked https://snipboard.io/ECOkpg.jpg. Are you saying 3D Print Toolbox is flawed and incorrect?

I say Zero-Faces are not errors. Just a possibility to dissolve details. Dissolving leads to faster printing, but facets will appear. Let the author decide what does he prefer: faster printing or better quality. By the way, if the printer's resolution is not high enough to reproduce these details – it will print it anyway – but the same way it would print a model with lower poly-count. I suggest to use higher density because it's either "win" or "no harm". Low density - you suggested - does not lead to "win" in any case – ESPECIALLY with rounded shapes.

@Yaroslav cool thanks for the clarification. I did say it was an error and did not mean to undermine your post. Since I only based it on my research where I saw a lot of posts claiming it is considered an error. But thanks for clarifying.

Thank you for this info. If you feel the comment is inappropriate you can flag it. Also I only expressed my opinion that it is way too dense. I don't see anything wrong with this opinion. I could be wrong though.

Thank you Harry McKenzie!

@HarryMcKenzie >>"Thank you for this info"<< — I feel necessary to add that warnings about Zero Faces/Edges not always can be ignored. — When faces or edges are precisely zeroes – this is a problem which should be fixed. — BUT these warnings quite often are "false positive" in case of high-density meshes, when faces/edges are small, but NOT zeroes (e.g., 0.046+ mm in case of the model I made) — So zero-size warnings should be neither always ignored or always worshipped – but rather dealt on the case to case basis *depending on the ACTUAL sizes of faces and edges.

@HarryMcKenzie — P.S. Since the model's high poly-count emerged such an extensive polemic :) - I've added a Decimate modifier to make poly-count easily adjustable — and also fixed a problem which really has been existing in my mesh – fixed overhang related to he grid's bottom. Updated file is in the UPD section of my answer.
